# Matching Apache HttpClient Response Interceptor to Request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Apache HttpClient has the HttpResponseInterceptor interface that has this method.

```
void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
```

How do I get the HttpRequest instance that resulted in this HttpResponse instance?

```
HttpClients.custom()
            .addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor)(response, context) -> {
                // how to get matching request?
            })
            .build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual HTTP request message as well other request execution details can be obtained from the execution context:

```
HttpClients.custom()
        .addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor) (response, context) -> {
            final HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
            final HttpRequest request = clientContext.getRequest();
        })
        .build();
```